# How do I do an AB test with a binary response variable?

Tags: r, probability, hypothesis-testing

I ran an AB test. I'd like to see if the conversion rate is significantly different between groups.

I know in an independent two-sample t-test, there are two vectors of numeric values (like height per observation) and then the mean of those two records is compared.

What do I do in this case? I don't have two vectors of numeric values.

Do I provide the vectors, but with 0 and 1 for `did convert` and `did not convert`?

Comment: It looks like the answer is to do a z-test. If that is right, please confirm http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-proportions-z-test-in-r

Comment: yes that's correct. note that its basically the same as your t test calculation (for the large samples of conversion rate studies). the essential inputs are the means and standard errors of the two groups.  note the restriction np >= 5 (or 10)  for all cells